# Handle currency symbol in backend in php

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I am using a `contentType: "application/JSON;charset=utf-8"` and passing a `currency symbol` and other details to the backend using a ajax request. Detail is like below.Currency symbol is `philipine pesa`.

[image]

But i am receive something else into the backend.

```
ac[company]=xyz&ac[site]=z.a.com&
ac[name]=Krunal&ac[cell_number]=+1123457&ac[email]=krunal@abc.com&
ac[currency]=PHP&ac[currency_symbol]=â‚±&ac[timezone]=America/Montserrat.
```

I am getting this `ac[currency_symbol]=â‚±` instead of the currency symbol.

Comment: yuo can pass using urn encode

Comment: @iCoders , like this : `Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8` , already tried.

Comment: How exactly are you *outputting* that string…? Where are you *viewing* it…?

Comment: I am viewing using a `print_r();`

Comment: And how are you ensuring that the *viewer* (browser?) is interpreting the output of `print_r` in the correct encoding?

Answer (score -1):

In HTTP headers default character set is ISO-8859-1 or ISO Latin-1, so it's diffrent from UTF-8 or ASCII, in other words , ISO-8859-1 is the character set of text-based content sent via HTTP.

As a suggestion, isntead of sending `₱` in your http request, you can send UTF-8 Currency Symbols. for example, the code for this Philippine PESO is `&#8369;`

you can find a list of all cuurencies and their hexadecimal (hex) reference [here](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_currency.asp)

Comment: The first sentence makes little sense; the second one is incorrect, that's an *HTML entity*, not a "UTF-8 Currency Symbol". And that in itself won't really solve the problem either, since now you need to decode that HTML entity if you want the actual character.

Answer (score -1):

You should not be needing to send the currency symbol over as you are already sending the [ISO 4217](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217) currency code over with the ajax request.  If you are needing to display a response with the currency symbol you can use do a database table lookup to find the symbol and return it as part of the response.